# Protocol Buffers - Why int32 and sint32 are mapped in the same way?

Tags: c++, int, mapping, buffer, protocols

In Protocol Buffers, there are several int types. For example, for 32 bits int, there are int32, sint32 and uint32.

In the documentation the difference is explained (see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar), but I don't understand why int32 and sint32 are mapped in the same way. They are actually mapped to ::google::protobuf::int32, so finally there is no difference, is there ?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, integers are usually signed. The `s` in `sint32` means signed. So it makes sense the two types maps the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory representation is same, but encoding is different. int32 uses varint and sint32 uses zig-zag varint. as varint is notoriously bad for negative integer.

For example,

```
memory value -> encoded value
int32 5 -> varint 5
int32 -5 -> varint -5
sint32 5 -> varint 10
sint32 -5 -> varint 9
```

Read more:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still don't understand one thing. We have a .proto file which we compile to C++ (so, sint and int are represented in the same way). So how the difference between them is made when encoding ?

Comment: The compiled c++ code has both memory representation and encoding method, as part of its field descriptor.

Comment: Ok I did not know. Thank you.